# Как из из бд удалить строку через pyqt

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

Допустим у меня есть QlineEdit и при нажатии кнопки я хочу удалять все строки которые с  ним совпадают.

```
    def delete(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb")
        self.cursor.execute("USE testdb")
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, col2 VARCHAR(45))")
        if self.lineEdit.text() != "":
            text = self.lineEdit.text()
            print(text)
            self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE col2 = text")
        print("success")
```

Появляется ошибка `-1073740791 (0xC0000409)`, хотя согласно документации, `sql` запрос выполнен правильно. Предполагаю, что проблема может быть в разнице типов данных, но как исправить это не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче ответ оказался вообще не очевидным. Я и вправду забыл внести изменения через `self.connection.commit()`, но итоговая строка с запросом выглядит так.

```
self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE col2 = '{}'".format(text))
```

Я нигде не находил до этого такой синтаксис до этого. Из объяснения моего знакомого я мало что понял, однако это что-то в духе `self.cursor.execute` не имеет своего собственного форматирования, поэтому он воспринимает `sql` запрос и сравнение с параметром как 2 отдельных сообщения. Был бы признателен, если у кого есть литература почему так.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот код ошибки `-1073740791 (0xC0000409)` вообще не несёт полезной информации0, к сожалению.

Предположу, что в вашем случае это может быть ошибка в заросе удаления строк из таблицы.
Вы используете просто текст без кавычек. Текстовые значения в запросах должны бтаться в кавычки, в противном случае, БД будет пытаться сравнить колонку `col2` с колонкой `text` (которого не существует в вашей таблице), вместо того чтобы искать строки значение в колонке `col2` которых равняется слову `text`.

```py
self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE col2 = text")
#--------------------------------------------------^^^^
#Должно быть так:
self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE col2 = 'text'")
```

В вашем же случае, как я понимаю, вы хотите удалить из таблицы БД строки значение `col2` которых соответствует значению в переменной `text`. В этом случае, вам нужно писать так:

```py
self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE col2 = %s", (text,))
```

И не забывайте делать `self.connection.commit()` после запросов вносящих изменения в БД, иначе эти изменения не будут применены.

Comment: Про %s я тоже находил инфу еще до этого, но в моем случае заработал мой ответ